# Keypress Function in Python Urwid

Tags: python, urwid

Forgive me if this is not a good question. I'm having hard time understanding one of the codes in URWID library in Python. This is one of the example code in the tutorial. http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html

```
 1 import urwid

 2 def exit_on_q(key):
 3   if key in ('q', 'Q'):
 4     raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

 5  class QuestionBox(urwid.Filler):
 6    def keypress(self, size, key):
 7      if key != 'enter':
 8        return super(QuestionBox, self).keypress(size, key)
 9      self.original_widget = urwid.Text(
 10       u"Nice to meet you,\n%s.\n\nPress Q to exit." %
 11       edit.edit_text)

 12  edit = urwid.Edit(u"What is your name?\n")
 13  fill = QuestionBox(edit)
 14  loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill, unhandled_input=exit_on_q)
 15  loop.run()
```

My questions are

1) Keypress function takes keystrokes as the input. I couldn't understand in which line of the code, keystrokes are being assigned to 'key' variable. It is directly used without any initialization in line 7

```
    if key != 'enter':
```

How is this possible?

2) Keypress function has not been called outside the QuestionBox class. Even without calling the function, why it is getting executed?

3) There is no **init** function defined inside the new class QuestionBox. Why it is not needed? I believe it should have both **init** and **super**  in class definitions.

4) what is the 'size' field in 'keypress' function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `key` is a parameter, so most likely whoever is calling the function is passing the most recently pressed key to it.
2. Since you have passed `fill` to `urwid.MainLoop`, and `QuestionBox` is inherited from an urwid class called `Filler`, the likely explanation is that `MainLoop` is calling the function with the appropriate parameters. According to documentation (Your link): "In `QuestionBox.keypress()` all keypresses except ENTER are passed along to the default `Filler.keypress()` which sends them to the child `Edit.keypress()` method."
3. If the constructor is not specified in a child class in Python, then the base class constructor is called automatically. Thus, neither `init` nor `super` are needed.
4. As for the size parameter, the documentation is somewhat unclear on what it is, but looking further should turn up an answer.

Update for #4:

[`size`](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Widget.keypress) is the size of the widget, although I am unsure what purpose this serves.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. First 2 answers are still not clear. What confused me with 12 and 13 lines in the code is, 'edit' is an instance of class 'Edit'. How can you inherit instance of a class?  As far as i know, common method is to inherit from the actual class but not from instance of a class.

Comment: It is still not clear how 'fill' inside the MainLoop( ) function is passing the 'key' arguement. Also, 'keypress' method inside the class should be called. It is not being called at all.Stil it is getting executed. This is making me insane.

Comment: Who said that you are inheriting from an instance? QuestionBox is derived from urwid.Filler, and the Edit is passed to Filler's constructor ([Source](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#filler)). You are mixing constructors and inheritance.

Comment: First, MainLoop is a class that is asking for a widget as its first parameter ([Source](http://urwid.org/reference/main_loop.html)). This class is assuming that you have defined a method keypress for the widget, and is calling the function whenever necessary through the base class interface (probably during run()).

Comment: Awesome. First part is clear now. Coming to the second part, How both parameters 'size' and 'key' have been passed through MainLoop function?

Comment: It is a class, first of all, and since mainloop has a QuestionBox(You passed it), during `run()`, it probably does something implementation specific like `question_box_name.keypress(size_of_questionbox, recent_key_pressed)`, where each of these variables were probably filled using some terminal specfic functions.

Answer (score 0):

@spectre, The QuestionBox class is inherited from the urwid.Filler class, which in turn has a method named keypress.